# Read from a file using a particular format

Tags: c++, file

I have this function:

```
void readClauses( ){
  char c = cin.get();
  while (c == 'c') {
    while (c != '\n') c = cin.get();
    c = cin.get();
  }

  string ccc;
  cin >> ccc >> numVars >> numClauses;
  clauses.resize(numClauses);

  for (uint i = 0; i < numClauses; ++i) {
    int literals;
    while (cin >> literals and literals != 0) clauses[i].push_back(literals); 
  }
}
```

I want do the same things in this function but instead digit the text i want read from a txt file. Someone can help me?

Comment: Please elaborate, its hard to tell exactly what you are asking.

Comment: show an example of an input file, it makes it easier to visualize what you want and how well it matches your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object of ifstream.

```
ifstream fin; //I named it fin, similar to cin
```

Now open the file you want input from

```
string file="input.txt";
fin.open(file,ios::in);
```

Where file is the name of the file. The file must be present in Output directory of your c++ file else you need to give full path.Now replace all your "cin" with "fin". Remember to write your input in your file. At last close the file opened using ifstream.

```
fin.close();
```

Now your code looks like this:

```
void readClauses( ){
  char c = fin.get();
  while (c == 'c') {
    while (c != '\n') c = fin.get();
    c = fin.get();
  }

  string ccc;
  fin >> ccc >> numVars >> numClauses;
  clauses.resize(numClauses);

  for (uint i = 0; i < numClauses; ++i) {
    int literals;
    while (fin >> literals and literals != 0) clauses[i].push_back(literals); 
  }
}
```

Don`t forget to include fstream file:

```
#include<fstream>
```

Comment: It's what i was looking for... but i have this error:

fin does not a name type

Comment: `fin` is an object of `ifstream` class present in `fstream` header file